# How to populate Radio Buttons in angularjs from variable in scope and collect any changes into scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to populate a pair of Yes or No radio buttons using angularjs.
I've a single value to do this from in $scope which is called x.employed.
x.employed has three possible values null, 'true' and 'false'.
How do I both make the Radio Button show the value from x.employed and then collect any subsequent change from the user.

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="x in FormList" >
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="x.employed" ng-model="new.employed" /> Yes &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" ng-value="x.employed" ng-model="new.employed" /> No
</div>
```

I've also tried ng-checked but as i understand it cant be used with ng-model. This has me completely confused can anyone throw some light on how i'd go about doing this please?

Comment: it will populate `ng-model` with values from `ng-value`, so if `x.employed` is already `false` by default, then for a _No_ you might want `ng-value="!x.employed"`

Comment: Thanks @Aleksey yes i see, ive tried and yes it will update the ng-model when i select a button, but the initial value from ng-value="x.employed" isn't setting the buttons on page load. I think it may have something to do with x.employed being a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.  First, value (or ng-value) needs to be set to the value associated with the button, Yes or No.  Second, ng-model should be set to the property in your object.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.FormList = [{
    employed: 'true'
  }, {
    employed: 'false'
  }, {
    employed: null
  }];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="sample">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Sample</title>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container" ng-repeat="x in FormList">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="radio" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="x.employed" /> Yes
      <input type="radio" ng-value="'false'" ng-model="x.employed" /> No
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @jbrown I appreciate your answer, however I probably didnt make myself clear. The x.employed value is coming in from database so I cant change that, its value will be one of three which are  null, 'true' and 'false' it seems such a simple thing to do but I cannot work it out, Ive tried so many permutations now.

Comment: @royG - I have modified my answer to use a bool instead of a string

Comment: Nope sorry @jbrown still cant get it working, even though  i render to the page and it contains x.employed : "true"

Comment: can you ignore the repeat I only want one set of yes no buttons

Comment: @royG - I misunderstood.  I thought the values were bool, true or false, but they are strings, 'true' or false'.  Answer updated to handle that.

Comment: Awesome it works Thankyou so much I have spent so much time on such a simple thing :)